# ¿Cómo puedo agregar Unit Tests a mi web api en c#?

Tags: c#, test, pruebas-unitarias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi arquitectura. Mi problema es que nose como realizar unit tests ya que  las operaciones se conectan con la base de datos a traves de Store procedures. ¿Existe alguna manera de hacer eso? o tengo que cambiar mi arquitectura.

Comment: A primera vista no comprendo el problema. ¿Qué impide que tus pruebas unitarias llamen a la API y que esta se conecte a la base de datos? Creo que la existencia de la base de datos debería ser transparente a este problema particular de implementar pruebas unitarias en tu sistema. ¿Podrías detallar más el problema?

Comment: Hola Roberto, gracias por responder. Mi problema es que nose como hacer "fake data" para poder realizar los tests ya que en la capa de Data Access existe lógica al trabajar con Store procedures. Entonces nose como encarar las pruebas

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que te ocurre. Un comentario se queda corto, te doy una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi opinión, tu sistema debería de abstraer un poco más la capa de acceso a datos. Deberías tener una interfaz que represente el acceso a datos. Nuestro objetivo es probar la API, independientemente de cómo sea el acceso a datos.

Una vez seas capaz de acceder a tus datos a través de una interfaz, el siguiente paso sería ser capaz de especificar qué instancia de qué clase (que implemente la interfaz) quieres usar para realizar el acceso a datos.

Una vez seas capaz de hacer esto, puedes implementar un acceso a datos en el que se obtenga de forma cómoda datos apropiados para realizar todas tus pruebas. Deberías ser capaz de implementar un servicio que te aporte datos de prueba. Esto se conoce como "mocking", y lo más cómodo para ti es que este servicio devuelva una serie de datos de prueba que procese los datos de unos ficheros en los que almacenes datos de prueba que quieras devolver. Ten en cuenta que este servicio no tiene por qué depender de una base de datos (de hecho, lo más cómodo es que no lo haga).

En este punto lo único que tienes que hacer es una build para desarrollo, que use tu acceso a datos actual (el que accede a la bd) y una build para test, que use el acceso a datos de test (el servicio de datos falsos).

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias Roberto, intentaré con interfaces